# Adding Days onto a date in a script

Tags: google-app-maker

I have two fields. One is 'Date Last Checked' the other is 'Date Due'. I need the 'Date due' to automatically be 364 days ahead of the 'Date Last Checked'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it comes down to this question: [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406)

...however it has some App Maker specificity. It seems that the right way to implement it from the Security standpoint will be using `onBeforeCreate` and `onBeforeSave` [Model Events](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events) and [Server Side script](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/server) to enforce data consistency:

```javascript
// Define this function somewhere in server scripts
function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}


// onBeforeCreate event handler
record.DueDate = addDays(record.LastChecked, 364);


// onBeforeSave event handler (to keep things simple we can
// update DueDate when any of record's fields is changed)
record.DueDate = addDays(record.LastChecked, 364);
```

Other benefits of this approach

- no need to duplicate logic in multiple places on UI
- updated DueDate will be returned with callback and automatically update UI